# INNODB: What ends a transaction?

Tags: mysql, innodb, transactions

My database wrapper needs to know when a statement is executed as part of a transaction (not auto committed). I'm setting a flag when beginTransaction() is called and clearing it again when commit() or rollback() are called.

The question is, what else could cause the transaction to end? For example, I will need to check for errors where the connection is lost or the transaction was killed due to a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

- Any DDL (`ALTER`, `DROP`, ...) terminates a transaction.  (This is unlike other vendors.)
- A hiccup in the network will terminate a transaction.  For this reason, it is [unwise to have 'auto-reconnect'](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2010/07/05/do-you-really-want-autoreconnect-to-silently-reconnect/) turned on. I suspect that if you have autocommit=0, you cannot recognize the hiccup.

I find it to be very risky to have `autocommit=0` -- it is too easy to forget (or otherwise fail) to perform the necessary `COMMIT`.  Instead, I prefer to have `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` in the *same* client subroutine.  Yes, this may force restructuring the subroutines differently, but, by having `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` 'together', I am less likely to mess up transactions.

Check for errors after *every* statement.  With Galera, even `COMMIT` can fail.  (Because that is when the other nodes are consulted.)